First letter uppercase or lowercase for a mobile app name
I'm designing an ai based mobile app and i was curious about using uppercase or lowercase letter as first letter of an app gives any difference in user likes. I wanted to know if people prefer capital letter or small letter as first letter of an app name.

This might be dependent on the target audience. What kind of app is it and who is it for?

In general, Title Case is more common in US, while sentence case is in other parts of the world. Things should be grammatically correct as much as possible. All lowercase for an app name will be alright if that is the logo.

This won't be the perfect answer you are looking for but I wanted to help a bit.
I am not sure on what people prefer as it depends on your target and the way to find out is by testing with them. But let me mention the GENERAL pros and cons that I am aware of
Pros of capitalizing the first letter of your app name:

Capitalizing the first letter can make the app name more easily readable, especially for multi-word names. It also gives the sense to the reader that it is a proper-noun and not a verb or whatsoever. When the app name comes in a sentance, and when the first letter is capitalised, it will stand out as well as easier for the reader to associate it with a name of a thing.
Both App Store & Play Store display app names with the first letter capitalized by default, regardless of how we submit it.

pros of not capitalizing the first letter of your app name:

your brand could appear more casual or modern.
wordplay - sometimes you could sneak it in a sentance and have double meanings.

General information that depends on your brand:

Uppercase first letters often convey a more formal or traditional feel, while lowercase can appear more casual or modern.


My suggestions for your next steps:

Test what appeals to your audience. (I don't personally like A/B testing, but I guess this is an ideal situation for it)
Considering how the name "looks" in various contexts – app icon, marketing materials, short sentances, long paragraphs.
See what other similar apps are doing and do the opposite to stand out on your positioning. {haha jk, up to you.}


It all depends on the user prespective or target audience and depends on the theme or name of app what you designing. so you can try Title Case or All Caps for that matter
